# Moving in 3D space in After Effects

Tags: 3d, effects

AE beginner here: I'm trying to create an effect such as this:

http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-video-5444182-business-people-loopable.php

Does anyone know of a tutorial or perhaps just point in the right direction on how to achieve this?

I only got as far a creating a null layer (parent of a few silhouettes), setting it to 3D, and playing with the scale which looks like it's not a good method..

Comment: Check out this website it has a lot of tutorials and is beginner friendly http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of playing with the scale, either move the null (or create a camera) and move it in Z (depth). Once you set the layer to 3D, the Z value is the 3rd parameter for the position.

Comment: thanks. Indeed, creating a Camera helped but my horizon is further down the screen than in the example so the silhouettes are not following the natural perspective. Is it to do with placing them in the 3D space or rather something with the camera do you think?

Comment: Make everything 3D and change all their depths (z position value) so they are staggered. That way when your camera animates forward, it passes them one by one. The preview window has a dropdown by default set to 'Active Camera', if you switch that to say, top, you'll get a birds-eye-view of where everything is and you can animate using that view as reference.